# Rails: Disable form field when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails application i have this two field in my form and i was trying to disable the end_date field when the check box is checked, but didn't succeed, So I'm wondering on how can i achieve this?
This is my form

```
<%= f.date_select :end_date, start_year: 1945 %> 
<%= f.check_box :is_current %>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this to your javascript file and it should work fine.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#checkBox_id").click(function() {
        var isDisabled = $(#checkBox_id).prop('checked')
        if(isDisabled) {
            $("#endDate_id").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#endDate_id").prop('disabled', true)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: my bad, remove the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simple JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("#dateCheck").click(function() {
    return $("#endDate").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
  });
});
```

And HTML

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="dateCheck" unchecked/>
    <input type="date" id="endDate" />
</body
```

Comment: Please explain "hasn't worked". It errors out? It shows the checkbox and the date field but the disable feature doesn't work?

Comment: Ok forgot my $(document... Just added this to a Rails app and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. When the checkbox is checked, each of the `select` fields generated by the default `date_select` in Rails will be disabled. If this still doesn't solve your problem, post your full form so we can have a better idea as to what's going on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id*='is_current']").click(function() {
    var isCurrent = $(this).prop("checked");
    var endDateSelects = $("[id*='end_date']");
    if (isCurrent == true) {
      endDateSelects.prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
      endDateSelects.prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```